# iOS UIView.animatewithDuration in Swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, uiviewanimation

It's a flyover animation using `UIMapKit` and basically animation begins with camera angle changing and after that spin around the object. I got error, and I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

> "**Pitch is the viewing angle of the camera, measured in degrees.** A
>   value of 0 results in a camera pointed straight down at the map.
>   Angles greater than 0 result in a camera that is pitched toward the
>   horizon by the specified number of degrees. If the map type is
>   satellite or hybrid, the pitch value is clamped to 0.
>
> The value in this property may be clamped to a maximum value to
>   maintain map readability. There is no fixed maximum value, though,
>   because the actual maximum value is dependent on the current altitude
>   of the camera."

Now, the problem is, according to code below, I initialize the `UIMapView` pitch value to 0. Down below, override func, when it's time for animation, I change the value to 65, so I expect the camera angle(pitch) would change, but when I run in the simulator, camera is still pointed straight down at the map. But the spin animation is working, because the heading between pitched camera and rotated camera has changed.

I don't know what's wrong with my pitch setting. Did I miss something? Should I add altitude property? Still try to figure that out.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapcamera

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let distance: CLLocationDistance = 700
    let pitch: CGFloat = 65
    let heading = 90.0
    var camera = MKMapCamera()
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7484405,
                                            longitude: -73.9856644)
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.mapType = .SatelliteFlyover

        camera = = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate,
                             fromDistance: distance,
                             pitch: 0,
                             heading: 0)
        self.mapView.camera = camera
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let pitchedCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate, fromDistance: distance, pitch: pitch, heading: 0)
        let rotatedCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate, fromDistance: distance, pitch: pitch, heading: 180)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
            self.mapView.camera = pitchedCamera

            }, completion: {
                (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(25.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
                    self.mapView.camera = rotatedCamera
                    }, completion: nil)

                })
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out the iOS simulator doesn't support flyover. So when I run it on a real device, my beautiful flyover animation appears just like I expect.